# Pass multiple arrays to HTML iFrame using Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js, code-formatting

I have looked at various documentation and similar questions on here, but cannot seem to find the particular solution. Apologies if I have missed anything obvious or have repeated this question!

As a bit of background info, I have implemented a graph using the Chart.js plugin and I am trying to pass the required data from a database.

The arrays of data are the following:

```
    loggedIn: [6.3, 2.4, 7.6, 5.4, 9.9, 7.8],
    available: [6.7, 2.2, 11.2, 5.5, 10.1, 7.9],
    availableForExisting: [7.2, 3.1, 8.2, 5.6, 9.2, 10.2],
```

My problem is that only one of the line graphs is being update whilst the rest aren't. The full Chart.JS iFrame code is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body onLoad="ready()">
<canvas id="myChart" width="250" height="200"></canvas>
<script>

    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");

    const loggedIn = [26, 36, 42, 38, 40, 30, 12];
    const available = [34, 44, 33, 24, 25, 28, 25];
    const availableForExisting = [16, 13, 25, 33, 40, 33, 45];
    const years = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    var myChart = new Chart(ctx,
    {
        type: 'line',
        data:
        {
            labels: years,
            datasets: [
            {
                label: 'Start Balance',
                data: loggedIn,//[], //start empty
                borderColor: 
                [
                    'rgba(164,126,44,1.000)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            },
            {
                label: 'Interest',
                data: available,//[], //start empty
                borderColor: 
                [
                    'rgba(5,99,59,1.000)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            },
            {
                label: 'End Balance',
                data: availableForExisting,//[], //start empty
                borderColor: 
                [
                    'rgba(255,148,112,1.000)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }            
        ]
        },
        options:
        {
            tooltips: 
            {
                callbacks: 
                {
                    label: function(tooltipItem, data) 
                    {
                        const title = data.labels[tooltipItem.index];
                        const dataset = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex];
                        const value = dataset.data[tooltipItem.index]; 
                        return title + ': ' + Number(value).toFixed(2) + "%";    
                    }
                },
            },

            onClick: handleClick
        }
    });

    window.onmessage = function(event)
    {

        if (event.data && Array.isArray(event.data))
        {
            myChart.data.datasets[0].data = event.data[0];
            myChart.data.datasets[1].data = event.data[1];
            myChart.data.datasets[2].data = event.data[2];
            myChart.update();
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("HTML Code Element received a generic message:");
            console.log(event.data);
        }
    };

    function handleClick(e)
    {
        var activeBars = myChart.getElementAtEvent(e);

        var value = myChart.config.data.datasets[activeBars[0]._datasetIndex].data[activeBars[0]._index];
        var label = activeBars[0]._model.label;

        window.parent.postMessage(
        {
            "type": "click",
            "label": label,
            "value": value
        }, "*");
    }

    function ready()
    {
        window.parent.postMessage(
        {
            "type": "ready"
        }, "*");
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I need to display the data in multiple line graphs, however only one is being updated. The way I am passing the data from the frontend is as follows:

```
let data = 
{
    loggedIn: [6.3, 2.4, 7.6, 5.4, 9.9, 7.8],
    available: [6.7, 2.2, 11.2, 5.5, 10.1, 7.9],
    availableForExisting: [7.2, 3.1, 8.2, 5.6, 9.2, 10.2],
};

$w("#html4").postMessage(data);
$w("#html4").onMessage((event) =>
{

    if (event.data.type === 'ready')
    {
        $w("#html4").postMessage(days[year]);
    }
});
```

Comment: Which one is being updated, the first or last, I would assume it would be the first, as in first glance of your code I see no loop looping over your data obj.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).